# can't crawl all pages in a website

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I was trying to crawl all the datas in all the pages . when i try to join the url i can't . I want to know what is the mistake i am doing

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import urlparse
from data.items import TextPostItem
from scrapy import optional_features
optional_features.remove('boto')

class RedditCrawler(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'reddit_crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['yellowpages.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=restaurant&geo_location_terms=California%2C%20KY']
    custom_settings = {
        'BOT_NAME': 'reddit-scraper',
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 7,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3
        }

def parse(self, response):
    s = Selector(response)
    next_link = s.xpath('//a[@class="next ajax-page"]/@href').extract()[0]
    full_link = urlparse.urljoin('http://www.yellowpages.com',next_link)


    yield self.make_requests_from_url(full_link)
    posts = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="search-results organic"]')
    for post in posts:
        item = TextPostItem()
        item['address']= post.xpath("//p[@class='adr']//text()").extract()
        item['business_name']= post.xpath("//a[@class='business-name']//text()").extract()
        item['phonenumber']= post.xpath("//div[@class='phones phone primary']//text()").extract()
        item['categories']=post.xpath("//div[@class='categories']//text()").extract()
        item['next_link']=post.xpath("//div[@class='pagination']//a[@class='next ajax-page']//@href").extract()

        yield item
```

Comment: Could you be more specific, please? "i can't" is not a good problem description.

Comment: check xpath for next link, I think it is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think your xpath `'//div[@class="next ajax-page"]//ul//li[6]//a/@href'` is incorrent. It doesn't work for me.

Try something simpler `'//a[@class="next ajax-page"]/@href'`

Comment: when i use xpath like this i am getting the following error                                                
 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: edit question and add this comment with full error message and show which line makes problem (the information is in error message)

Comment: btw: new problem can have nothing to do with previous problem - then you have to create new question  on SO.